# How to cancel user consent to a web application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I recently logged into a web application and I got the standard user consent dialog.
I clicked "Accept".
How do I get to that dialog again or cancel?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: See that text "You can change your permissions at https://myapps.microsoft.com" - you have tried that, of course.

Comment: You are talking about canceling user consent, not administrator consent, right?

Comment: Hi, Did this solve your problem?

Comment: I think ALL of you misunderstood my question. I am sorry if this was not more clear. I don't want to go to Azure. Suppose I logged in to one of YOUR websites as a user, and it was a multi-tenant website. The first time I go there, I would get the consent dialog above. After I Accept, how do I change my mind? I want to see this dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel the user's consent to the web application through the UI. You can revoke the administrator's consent to the application through the Azure portal. However, this obviously does not apply to the user's consent.

However, you can cancel user consent through power shell. First go to **Enterprise Applications**>**your application**>**Permissions**>**User consent** and you will see all user consent permissions.

[image]

Next, you can then click **Review permissions** -> **This application has more permissions than I want**. This will give you a PowerShell script that you can run to remove all user consent for that application. It can of course be customized to only remove certain permissions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think ALL of you misunderstood my question. I am sorry if this was not more clear. I don't want to go to Azure. Suppose I logged in to one of YOUR websites as a user, and it was a multi-tenant website. The first time I go there, I would get the consent dialog above. After I Accept, how do I change my mind? I want to see this dialog again.